# How can we create subdirectories under picture directory given by Android OS (From Android 13 onwards)?

Tags: directory, subdirectory, file-storage, android-13

From Android 13 onwards, the way of capturing image and storing into internal storage has been changed. So now Android 13 onwards you  will get built in directory to store your images(captured/any). SO System will give you a path like- "**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/yourPKG name/files/Pictures/**". SO here you can store your image files. My requirement is I want to create subdirectories under "**Picture**" directory. But, system is not allowing me to do that. How can we achieve this?

I tried to create subdirectories under Picture directory  like "**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/PKG name/files/Pictures/Master/Child/ChildOne/one.jpg**" and tried to save my capture image there. Path is getting created but getting exception that no such a file or directory.